# Is/are there any difference(s) in batter from French and Italian macaron methods?

Tags: baking, macarons

I've kept things simple with the French method so far, and I've always been very nervous about over macaronnage-ing, but I just watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yowvMAQ8HD8) in which the host used the Italian method and seemed to just go to town on the batter (once the tant pour tant is incorporated) like there was no risk of over-doing the macaronnage step.

Does the syrup in the Italian method make the meringue more resilient as it cools? Are there any other differences between the results of the two methods than simply how they're achieved?

Any comments about preferred methods would be appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how I missed this answer before I posted the question, it wasn't a very difficult thing to Google... Anyway, here seem to be the differences between the results of the two methods:

1. French

   - Softer/chewier
   - Less sweet
   - Less stable
   - Smaller feet
2. Italian

   - Crispier/more powdery
   - Sweeter
   - Larger feet
   - Much more stable

As far as I can tell the smooth, matte, fancy looking macarons seen across the internet are the Italian method (I'm guessing that the syrup helps with the shell). The French method is less steps, but I will definitely need to give the Italian method a shot!

Sources:

- [Love and Macarons](http://loveandmacarons.blogspot.com/2013/04/french-meringue-method-vs-italian.html)
- [Indulge with Mimi](http://www.indulgewithmimi.com/french-vs-italian-meringue-macarons/)

Comment: Which one give tasty macarons ? Sometimes my macarons when baked have a smell of macaroons (egg whites mixed with coconut)

Comment: I think that both give tasty macarons! I think the French method may have slightly more flavor because there's not as much sugar in the shells

Comment: And why sometimes taste like macaroons ? Because an extra baking where the almonds are slightly burnt ?

Comment: I'm not sure why :/ I don't know what your recipe or techniques are! Try googling "trouble shoot macarons" and see if you can find something that way